# Android Gradle Build with Platform Signing

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a project, which needs to be signed with the platform signature before deployment. I am using an external tool after building with gradle, and this slows down the build process.

While using Eclipse, I could define an external builder, which would run the signing batch and produce the platform-signed output. I could not find any such option with Android Studio/Gradle.

Note: the "signingConfigs" settings does not meet my need, as it only gets a java keystore and applies the application signature, not the platform signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, your problem is the *manual step* required after the gradle build.

You can easily add an *external job* (i.e. an *additional task*) after the build with "[mustRunAfter](https://docs.gradle.org/2.1/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:ordering_tasks)" and an [Exec](https://docs.gradle.org/2.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html) task. You will still use the external tool, but at least this step will be integrated in the normal gradle build.

```
task doThePlateformSignature(type:Exec) {
   //on windows:
   //adapt to your needs to invoke your external tool
   commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'arg0', 'arg1', ...

}

task doThePlateformSignature.mustRunAfter build
```

Comment: Thanks, but I could not get when this task will be invoked. Do I need to manually call it?  Also, I need to give the output apk file as parameter, can I give parameters to this task?

Comment: doThePlatformSignature will be executed after the build task. You can get the apk in build/output/apks/theapkname.apk. You cannot pass a parameter to the task. If you need to do it for multiple apks: you have to [create multiple tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html)